# pick two images separately from gallery in one activity in android

Tags: android, image, android-intent, gallery, onactivityresult

I have an activity that contains two imageViews.

I want to pick image separately from gallery for each one.

what should I do in on-Activity-Result to set each image-View background correctly?

thanks.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 2 OnClickListener on your 2 ImageViews. There you set the current ImageView. In onActivityResult you can now set the selected picture from gallery to the current ImageView.

> ```
>  ImageView currentImageView = null;
>  //...
>  imageview1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
>       @Override
>       public void onClick(View v){
>             currentImageView = v;
>             // start gallery intent and take picture
>       }
>  });
>
>  imageview2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
>       @Override
>       public void onClick(View v){
>             currentImageView = v;
>             // start gallery intent and take picture
>       }
>  });
>
>  @Override
>  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
>    switch(requestCode){
>        case TAKE_PICTURE_FROM_GALLERY:
>            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
>                uri = //... get Uri
>                currentImageView.setImageUri(uri)
>            }
>            break;
>     }
>  }
> ```

Comment: nice to hear, pls mark this post as answeared. so other users realize you found your answear